# How can I tersely create JavaScript array of arrays, with different lengths for each array (each row has a different, specified length)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create a Javascript array to represent the layout of tables in a room:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 
17 18 19
```

I have done this so far:

```
this.CHART = Array(4).fill(0).map((x, i) => Array(5).fill(0).map((y, j) => j));
```

...which produces this array:

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
```

This is very close to the requirement, but now I'm in over my head trying to assign the correct values, and assigning a different size to each array.

This smelly version works to create the required array, but I think there must be a better way, that will be helpful to me and to others reading this post in the future:

```
ROW_1 = [];
ROW_2 = [];
ROW_3 = [];
ROW_4 = [];

const ROW_1_SIZE = 5;
const ROW_2_SIZE = 7;
const ROW_3_SIZE = 5;
const ROW_4_SIZE = 3;

ROW_1 = Array(ROW_1_SIZE).fill(0).map((x, i) => i + 1);
ROW_2 = Array(ROW_2_SIZE).fill(0).map((x, i) => i + 1 + ROW_1_SIZE );
ROW_3 = Array(ROW_3_SIZE).fill(0).map((x, i) => i + 1 + ROW_1_SIZE + ROW_2_SIZE );
ROW_4 = Array(ROW_4_SIZE).fill(0).map((x, i) => i + 1 + ROW_1_SIZE + ROW_2_SIZE + ROW_3_SIZE );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep a counter for the values in a closure.

```js
var lengths = [5, 7, 5, 3],
    result = lengths.map((i => length => Array.from({ length }, _ => i++))(0));

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Without IIFE

`mapWithValue` is a function which expects a value and returns a callback for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for creating an array and maps increased values.

```js
const mapWithValue = i => length => Array.from({ length }, _ => i++);

var lengths = [5, 7, 5, 3],
    result = lengths.map(mapWithValue(0));

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I didn't realize that providing a length property inside of an object literal was enough to consider it array-like, and I'm really surprised and a bit confused by the persistence of `i`. I feel like I have a mental blind-spot, but could you explain how that works? I don't get how `i` carries over after the first IIFE is completed.

Comment: maybe the second approach with an outside function makes clear, what's happening. the closure covers `i` in the scope of the returned callback for further use.

Comment: Yep, that helped it click! Thanks!

Comment: GREAT answer! @NinaScholz is it against the rules to ask a follow-up question? I simplified my requirements for the sake of an easy to read question, but I actually need each element of the row arrays to be an object: { table_number: i, seats_left: s }...I'm still wrapping my head around your answer and can't see where to make that modification.

Comment: i have no idea of the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz, sorry, should I clarify? In the question, for the sake of simplicity, I asked for an array with simple elements: [0, 1, 2, 3,...], but I probably should have specified that I actually need an _array of objects_: [{ num: **0**, seats_left: null}, {num: **1**, seats_left:null}, {num: **2**, seats_left: null}...], where the nulls are just placeholders that I will assign values to later in my code.

Comment: @NinaScholz, apologies...after re-re-reading the Array.from()  docs, I arrived at this: `.map((i => length => Array.from({ length }, _ => ({'num': i++, 'seats': null})    ))(0));`. I hope this will help future programmers searching for something similar.

Comment: great, you found it.